# Remove ECS data from metricbeat for smaller documents

Tags: elasticsearch, time-series, metricbeat, elastic-beats

I use the graphite beat to get graphite protocol metrics into es.
The metric document is much bigger than the metric data itself (timestamp, value, metric name).

I also get all the ECS data inserted and I think it will make my queries much slower (and my documents much bigger) and I don't need this data.

Can I remove the ECS data somehow in the metricbeat configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use [Metricbeat's `drop_fields` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/drop-fields.html), but it might not be able to remove all the fields you specify as some are added after the processor chain.

So, acting on the ES side will guarantee you that you can change the event source the way you like. Also if you have many Beats deployed, you only need to configure this in a single place.

One way to achieve this is to create an index template for Metricbeat events and attach an ingest pipeline to it.

```
PUT _index_template/my-template
{
    "index_patterns" : [
      "metricbeat-*"
    ],
    "template" : {
      "settings" : {
        "index" : {
          "lifecycle" : {
            "name" : "metric-lifecycle"
          },
          "codec" : "best_compression",
          "default_pipeline" : "metric-pipeline"
        }
      },
   ...
```

Then the `metric-pipeline` would simply look like this and remove all the fields listed in the `field` array:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/metric-pipeline
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "remove": {
        "field": ["agent", "host", "..."]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can I use "Metricbeat's drop_fields processor" on a specific module (Graphite) and not all of them? Because we use also the system beat (for example) and I want only the graphite beat to drop all of the ECS metadata. And it seems the processors are being set on the metricbeat.yml which affects all the modules.

Comment: Yes, you can [define a condition](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/defining-processors.html#conditions) on the `event.module` field in order to activate the processor just for the graphite module

Comment: I couldn't remove these fields: 'host', 'agent', and 'ecs'. Is there a way of removing them in the metricbeat context and not in the elasticsearch with a pipeline?

Comment: As I said, I think they are added after the processors have run, so I'm afraid it's not possible, you'll need to do it at the ES level. However, this feels like an premature optimization and you know [what they say about them](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) ;-)... Just modify your mapping to not index those fields and you're good to go.

Comment: If I put the processor under the metrics.yml and not under the module it filters everything.

Comment: Yes, but you only wanted to filter out those fields for the graphite module